# GPUImage - MovieWriter, nothing happens for a while after "setCompletionBlock"

Tags: ios, gpuimage

Been struggling with this for a couple of days now. I'm processing a video with a filter, it saves the video just fine. However, after it's saved, it takes a long time to update the UI. I can see the video in iTunes (with iTunes file sharing), a long time before the UI is updated.

I create the view like this, and add that to my view controller. This is just so the user can preview the video and select filter.

```
-(GPUImageView*)playClipWithClip:(MYClip*)clip
{
    _clip = clip;
    _filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320)];

    _movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:[self urlForCurrentClip]];
    _movieFile.runBenchmark = NO;
    _movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
    _movieFile.shouldRepeat = YES;

    [self changeFilter];
    return _filterView;
}
```

When the user wants to save the video I have this method:

```
-(void)saveClipWithFilter
{
    [_movieFile cancelProcessing];

    _movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
    _movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = NO;
    _movieFile.shouldRepeat = NO;

    NSString *movieName = [self fileNameForGeneratedClip];
    NSString *generatedMovieNameWithPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",movieName];

    NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:generatedMovieNameWithPath];
    unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

    _movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(568, 320.0)];
    [_filter addTarget:_movieWriter];

    _movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = NO;
    [_movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:_movieWriter];

    [_movieWriter startRecording];
    [_movieFile startProcessing];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [_movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"**************************** DONE ****************************");
        [weakSelf.filter removeTarget:weakSelf.movieWriter];
        [weakSelf.movieWriter finishRecording];

        [weakSelf exitVideoEditingModeAndSave];
    }];
}
```

My method `[weakSelf exitVideoEditingModeAndSave];` is called. And that method in turn calls the delegate (my view controller).

The problem is that after my delegate is called and my `NSLog` shows, it will take about 10 seconds for the view to update. I know that the file is ready and has been saved.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a threading issue, in your completion block, dispatch to the main thread before you update any UI elements

Comment: Specifically, AppKit doesn't allow other threads to start sending messages to views. (At least, not without RPC like NSDistantObject)